# Looping through items in an object for google sheets

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through an array that is part of a JSON object from a page speed insights call to add all of the unused javascript Urls to a google sheet using the script editor.

Here is an example of the JSON object:

```json
  "audits": {
    "unused-javascript": {
      "id": "unused-javascript",
      "title": "Remove unused JavaScript",
      "description": "Remove unused JavaScript to reduce bytes consumed by network activity. [Learn more](https://web.dev/unused-javascript/).",
      "score": 0.43,
      "scoreDisplayMode": "numeric",
      "numericValue": 1350,
      "numericUnit": "millisecond",
      "displayValue": "Potential savings of 231 KiB",
      "details": {
        "type": "opportunity",
        "headings": [
          {
            "key": "url",
            "valueType": "url",
            "subItemsHeading": {
              "key": "source",
              "valueType": "code"
            },
            "label": "URL"
          },
          {
            "key": "totalBytes",
            "valueType": "bytes",
            "subItemsHeading": {
              "key": "sourceBytes"
            },
            "label": "Transfer Size"
          },
          {
            "key": "wastedBytes",
            "valueType": "bytes",
            "subItemsHeading": {
              "key": "sourceWastedBytes"
            },
            "label": "Potential Savings"
          }
        ],
        "items": [
          {
            "url": "https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1926350194273730?v=2.9.2=stable",
            "totalBytes": 140229,
            "wastedBytes": 108197,
            "wastedPercent": 77.15757011763822
          },
          {
            "url": "https://static.example.com/domain.us.modern.bundle.a02fef045566caf5d464.js",
            "totalBytes": 306716,
            "wastedBytes": 106243,
            "wastedPercent": 34.63892414884589
          },
          {
            "url": "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KZ",
            "totalBytes": 127214,
            "wastedBytes": 21845,
            "wastedPercent": 17.17151000374831
          }
        ],
        "overallSavingsMs": 1350,
        "overallSavingsBytes": 236285
      }
    },
```

I am attempting to loop through the "items" array within the "unused-javascript" object and get all of the urls to show in google sheets.

Here is the code I have within the script editor. When I run this, only one URL shows on the sheet. However, I am trying to get all of the URLs added to the sheet.

```js
function pageSpeed(Url) {
  var key = "AIzaSyAyHY";

    var serviceUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + Url + "&key=" + key;

    var array = [];
  
    if (key == "YOUR_API_KEY")
        return "Please enter your API key to the script";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

        if ((content != null) && (content["lighthouseResult"] != null)) {

                if (content["captchaResult"]) {
                      var timetointeractive = content["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["interactive"]["displayValue"].slice(0, -2);
                      var firstcontentfulpaint = content["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"].slice(0, -2);
                      var firstmeaningfulpaint = content["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["first-meaningful-paint"]["displayValue"].slice(0, -2);
                      var speedindex = content["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["speed-index"]["displayValue"].slice(0, -2);
                      var unusedJs = content["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["unused-javascript"]["details"]["items"];
                          for (var i = 0; i < unusedJs.items.length; i++) {
                              var unusedUrl;
                              unusedUrl = unusedJs[i]["url"]
                   }
                }
             else {
                      var timetointeractive = "An error occured";
                      var firstcontentfulpaint = "An error occured";
                      var firstmeaningfulpaint = "An error occured";
                      var speedindex = "An error occured";
                      var unusedJs = "An error occured";
            }
        }

    var currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/');

    array.push([timetointeractive, firstcontentfulpaint, firstmeaningfulpaint, speedindex, currentDate, "complete", unusedUrl]); 
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    return array;
}
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: `array.push()` should be within the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

Take a look below at my usage of `Array.prototype.map`. That's the simpler route.

Your `for` loop would work just as well IF you declared `unusedUrl` outside of (ie. before) the loop AND pushed to an existing array. As it is, there's an issue of scope, so `unusedUrl` is redeclared on every iteration, meaning you'll only assign the last iteration's value to `unusedUrl`.

Both solutions are below.

Using `map`

```js
var content = {
  lighthouseResult: {
    audits: {
      'unused-javascript': {
        // Other stuff
        details: {
          // Other stuff
          items: [
            {
              url:
                'https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1926350194273730?v=2.9.2=stable',
              totalBytes: 140229,
              wastedBytes: 108197,
              wastedPercent: 77.15757011763822,
            },
            {
              url:
                'https://static.example.com/domain.us.modern.bundle.a02fef045566caf5d464.js',

              totalBytes: 306716,
              wastedBytes: 106243,
              wastedPercent: 34.63892414884589,
            },
            {
              url: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KZ',
              totalBytes: 127214,
              wastedBytes: 21845,
              wastedPercent: 17.17151000374831,
            },
          ],
          overallSavingsMs: 1350,
          overallSavingsBytes: 236285,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

var items = content.lighthouseResult.audits['unused-javascript'].details.items
var unusedUrls = items.map(item => item.url) // OR, using es6, items.map(({ url }) => url)

console.log(unusedUrls)
```

Using `for`

```
var items = content.lighthouseResult.audits['unused-javascript'].details.items

var unusedUrls = []

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  unusedUrls.push(items[i]['url'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! When implementing the empty array and for loop that you provided I am still seeing only a single script result in the google sheet. Is this a limitation within google sheets or am I missing something else?